# are there UML models of the OGC standards available online (native files not pdfs)

Tags: web-service, metadata, ogc

Last time I checked, there were only [PDFs](http://www.iso.org/iso/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=39229) with class diagrams available on the net (downloadable for at least 140 swiss francs a piece) , but not the UML models in a native format of a database modeling tool.

These PDFs are a pain in the neck to work with.

In the appendix of some standards documents there were xml printouts. For GML there are xsd files available but they are very complex. For geographic metadata there are some xsds defined in [this PDF](http://www.iso.org/iso/iso_catalogue/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=32557&commid=54904).

Luckily, parts of this document is available [here](http://eden.ign.fr/xsd/isotc211/isofull/20090316/gmd/view), for instance. it says at the top of each xsd file:

> This file was generated from ISO
>   TC/211 UML class diagrams == 01-26-2005 12:40:02

Are these UML models of the OGC standards available online somewhere?
Maybe someone has converted these ##### xsds to a more usable format?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I know, UML models are not included with OGC specifications. FYI, the full set of XSDs for published specifications are available here: http://schemas.opengis.net/. Also, you should be able to download the OGC specs (not ISO) for free from here. You could also ask Carl Reed or Raj Singh about making any of UML available, their emails are here: http://www.opengeospatial.org/ogc/organization/staff

Comment: Ah, http://schemas.opengis.net/, I remember that site. I'll contact these guys when I really need to work with the OGC standards, now I just wanted to have a brief look. I think I can get a head-start by throwing some xpath-expressions at the xsds.

Answer (score 2):

Following this discussion http://www.ogcnetwork.net/node/1323, it seems you must refer to UML ISO diagrams for most UML OGC diagrams.
You can get this diagrams on http://www.isotc211.org/hmmg/HTML/

Comment: That's also a useful answer. These interactive reports (presumably exported from someone's Enterprise Architect) showing clickable imagemaps are indeed a bit better than class diagrams in PDFs.

Answer (score 1):

CSIRO makes them available:
https://www.seegrid.csiro.au/wiki/AppSchemas/HollowWorld

Also look at ShapeChange as a way to transform UML to GML

Answer (score 0):

NOT OGC But open
ESRI used to have a some uml models with a few of the geodatabase models. I think last look I couldn't find one for what I was working on. You might dig arounnd...
I did hit a familiar area and found the case tools import.

[Gdb Model page @ ESRI](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/geodatabase/data-models.html)

[Utility Model Tools](http://support.esri.com/en/downloads/datamodel/detail/24)